# Increment Groups values base on match of another col

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
ColA            ColB
March           101
April           201
April           202
May             301
March           102
March           103
April           203
May             302
```

I am trying to figure out a formula that will allow me to match the instances in ColA and increment the groups in in ColB

Answer (score 0):

In B1 put `101`.  In B2 put:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A2,A2)=1,((INT(MAX($B$1:$B1)/100)+1)*100)+1,MAX(INDEX(($A$1:$A1=A2)*$B$1:$B1,))+1)
```

Then copy down.

[image]